# Using knockoutjs with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, knockout.js

I'm just starting out with Knockout (and javascript for that matter). The problem is I'm trying to use jqGrid similar to the way Sanderson is using the jqGrid in his [Knockout Grid Example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html).

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzMGn/1/) I've got so far. I'm obviously missing something but I can't tell what it is, since the grid doesn't even show up.

Comment: Does you fiddle references knockoutjs anywhere? I couldn't find it

Comment: Also, have you tried to debug? do you have any error messages?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Yeah. Should be the first reference I added. Not sure what to really debug.

Comment: You can use the browser's developer tool. Every major browser has it. You should be able to see the error messages on the console. Check this article to know more about debugging: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273129/Beginner-Guide-to-Page-and-Script-Debugging-with-C

Comment: @Dan - In the Knockout Grid example Steve isn't using jqGrid, he rolls his own grid, is this what you want to do or does it have to use jqGrid? KO makes it easy to do these things without requiring third party components.

Comment: @madcapnmckay I'm looking to use jqGrid specifically. I haven't found any example of it being used with knockout, which is kind of surprising.

Comment: @Dan it's not that surprising since as I said, KO means you don't need to use it and could easily roll your own grid. I'll see if I can get something working for you.

Comment: @Dan KO should work regardless of which "grid" you're using. Search on KnockoutJS Google Groups and you'll find at least a couple of good samples. Here's one: http://jsfiddle.net/yauhen/zjbLF/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Fiddle has a lot of issues.  None of your sources for jqGrid are coming through. Direct linking to github isn't supported using the urls you've used.  Lastly and most importantly.  You don't have a binding handler for jqGrid.

**Binding Handlers**

```
data-bind="handlergoeshere:{options go here}"
```

There is no default jqGrid binding handler as part of KnockoutJS.  So to get jqGrid to work with knockout like this you would need to use a 3rd party binding handler.  I've found only one example of a working jqGrid binding handler here: http://jsfiddle.net/yauhen/zjbLF/5/  I'm not sure how fully functional it is with regard to observable properties working yet though.

Since you're just starting out in Knockout, I would recommend not getting too head over heels yet in the more complicated pieces like creating your own custom binding handlers.  There is a grid control being developed called koGrid which you can find on github here: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid which is going to be easier to implement and understand than your current path.

Good luck, and happy coding!